# How to use Phonegap plugins in Xcode?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, phonegap-plugins

Hereby I have one link for plugins, but I don't know the correct steps to add a plugins to work it out. Please help me out with proper steps..Adding tutorial points would be appreciated.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question and this [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/eXzriHzKpmw) thread helped me in the end. It's for later versions of phonegap / cordova (2.0 and above I suspect), the calling convention was different for earlier versions and many threads refer to these and are now out-of-date.